# Ubuntu 12.04 - Unable to mount location

Tags: 12.04, mount, hard-drive

When I try to select my secondary HDD (internal HDD) I get this error message:

Unable to mount location
Error creating moint point: No such file or directory

What kind of sorcery is this?

This is in my fstab:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0
# / was on /dev/sdb6 during installation
UUID=75537d5d-c9bb-416b-8a6e-10e4c237048e /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sdb7 during installation
UUID=39336cba-ed61-47c2-954c-500d9022f444 none            swap    sw     

     0       0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A little clarifacation on the mount command, found [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Mount).

> The command
>
> ```
> mount
> ```
>
> Is responsible for mounting filesystems. The syntax for this command is quite simple (remember that mount must be run with super user privideges to change the system) so:
>
> ```
> sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
> ```
>
> Will mount the filesystem on /dev/sda1 (which may be a USB drive, a SATA drive or a SCSI >drive) into the folder /mnt. That means that going into /mnt will show you the filesystem >which is on /dev/sda1.

Answer (score 1):

Giving this error, you're trying to mount your HDD on a mount point (a.k.a. a directory) that doesn't exist.
If your using `/etc/fstab` file, make sure you write the right place as a mount point. If your using `mount MyHDD mountPoint`, make sure "mountPoint" exists.

Comment: I have edited the question. On the other hand, what is mount MyHDD mountPoint? I cann't find it.

Answer (score 0):

These other answers will work. But could get annoying mounting every time you log in. Here are some instructions to mount the hdd on boot...

Firstly I'd try to find the UUID of the secondary HDD. Typing `sudo BLKID` into a terminal ([how to open a terminal](http://www.sudo-juice.com/open-a-terminal-in-ubuntu/)). This will output details about your connected HDD's, make a note of the UUID for the secondary HDD.

First create a directory to mount to:

```
sudo mkdir /media/secondary
```

Now add a line to the end of your fstab file:

```
UUID='the-uuid'     /media/secondary    ext4    defaults 0 0
```

Obviously replace 'the-uuid' with the UUID you found before (and remove the '')!

Then type `sudo mount all` which will mount all the entries in the fstab, including the one you just entered.