# Unable to Mount Location Can't mount file

Tags: 12.04, mount, filesystem

I am new to ubuntu. I installed ubuntu 12.10 and then at the installation process defined the partition and mount parameters. e.g.

1. /dev/sda1
2. /dev/sda2
3. /dev/sda3

so on...

But after the installation is completed, System is not showing the drives as expected. There was a single drive listed name 500 GB Hard Disk. On Selecting this drive its giving me the error mentioned in the title. I searched some answers from the [askubuntu forums](https://askubuntu.com/questions/143718/mount-you-must-specify-the-filesystem-type) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/196810/ubuntu-12-04-unable-to-mount-location). but I am unable to mount the drive still. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is nothing to be concerned about. This happens due to partitioning - the "500 GB Hard Disk" icon represents your entire SDA tree, so it can't be mounted as a single volume.

Next to that icon, you will see a folder called "File System" that represents the base of your Linux installation. Any other operating systems or data partitions should be accessible from your desktop, and will be labeled "xGB File System" where x is the amount of space in that partition.

Comment: Is there any other way to show these drives at the front along with the filesystem just like in ubuntu 11.04 etc?

Comment: If you're willing to switch desktop environments. I recommend ditching Unity altogether, I think it's a hot mess and no one decent in Linux is going to tolerate having a locked interface shoved down their throats anyway. There's no way to switch file managers in it which is what you need to do to achieve that. Classic GNOME, LXDE, and KDE will all allow you to customize which graphical file manager you want to use.

Comment: Thanks. I switched to kubuntu to gradually handle the pressure and to understand the structure as I found kubuntu somewhat easier than ubuntu